# Get days on basis of Sum of values from DaysLIST

Tags: c#, math

Lets suppose i have list of days :

- Sun - 1
- Mon - 2
- Tue - 4
- Wed - 8
- Thu - 16
- Fri - 32
- Sat - 64

Now user can select one or more then one from checklist .My database just storing the sum of days (Example: if user selected sun and mon then value is getting stored in database is 3) .now i want to show user days he selected. What will be the formula to compute this.

Should i write a binary logic for this ??

Comment: If you are storing as binary, binary logic should be the way to work with it. But as @SergeyBerezovskiy says, what have you **actually** tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) enum for week days to treat them as a bit field:

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{
   Sun = 1,
   Mon = 2,
   Tue = 4,
   Wed = 8,
   Thu = 16,
   Fri = 32,
   Sat = 64
}
```

Then save to database

```
WeekDays value = WeekDays.Sun | WeekDays.Mon; // Sun, Mon
```

When reading from database use [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to verify if value contains given week day (if given bit field is set in enum value):

```
WeekDays value = ReadValueFromDatabase();

foreach(WeekDays day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays)))
{
    if (value.HasFlag(day))
       // day is selected
}
```

That is same as usage of bitwise operation:

```
(value & day) == day
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Day
{

    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
}

Day d = Day.Friday | Day.Saturday;

Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine((int)d);
```

This prints:
Friday, Saturday and 96

Or what Sergey just posted before me...

Answer (score 1):

Create a procedure that will get the remainder of the sum either from the database or not

```
<pre>
private int GetRemainder(int DaySum)
{
    int xRemainder = 0;

    if(DaySum > 64)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 64;
    else if(DaySum > 32)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 32;
    else if(DaySum > 16)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 16;
    else if(DaySum > 8)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 8;
    else if(DaySum > 4)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 4;
    else if(DaySum > 2)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 2;
    else if(DaySum > 1)
        xRemainder = DaySum % 1;

    return xRemainder;
}
private string SelectedDay(int SumValue)
{
    if((SumValue/64) > 0)
        return "Saturday";
    else if((SumValue/32) > 0)
       return "Friday";
    else if((SumValue/16) > 0)
        return "Thursday";
    else if((SumValue/8) > 0)
        return "Wednesday";
    else if((SumValue/4) > 0)
        return "Tuesday";
    else if((SumValue/2) > 0)
        return "Monday";
    else if((SumValue/1) > 0)
        return "Sunday";
}
</pre>
```

Have variables to store the values

```
<pre>
int SumOfDaysSelected = 0;
string DaysSelected = "";
</pre>
```

Then create conditions to check what day or days are selected depending on the value of the variable SumOfDaysSelected

```
<pre>
while(SumOfDaysSelected > 0)
{
if(DaysSelected == "")
    DaysSelected = SelectedDay(SumOfDaysSelected);
else
    DaysSelected = DaysSelected + "," + SelectedDay(SumOfDaysSelected);

SumOfDaysSelected = GetRemainder(SumOfDaysSelected);
}
</pre>
```